# *ngFor is showing an error of undefined when trying to loop over an object in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, spring-boot

I get the below error when trying to loop over an object using *ngFor directive in angular:

> Type 'Inventory' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.
> 18         <tr *ngFor="let item of searchedInventory;">

but the searchedInventory has data in it when I console logged it -
`{id: 1, foodName: 'idli', foodDescription: 'made from rice', date: '2023-02-07 16:14:37.793398+05:30', price: 30, …}`

The component.ts file as below,

```
 searchedInventory!: Inventory;
  constructor(private inventoryDataService : InventoryDataService, private route : ActivatedRoute){
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
   this.foodname = this.route.snapshot.params['foodname'];
   this.searchedItems();
  //  console.log(this.foodname);
   

  }
  
  foodname!: String;

  searchedItems(){
    this.inventoryDataService.retrieveFoodByName(this.foodname).subscribe(
      response => {
        // console.log(response);
        this.searchedInventory = response;
        console.log(this.searchedInventory);
        
      }
    )
  }
```

my HTML page is,

```
<h1>List of foods:</h1>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Food Name</th>
            <th>Food Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Hotel Name</th>
            <th>Hotel Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of searchedInventory;">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.foodName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.foodDescription}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price}}</td>
            <td>{{item.date}}</td>
            <td>{{item.hotelName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.hotelAddress}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-success">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Editted,
I tried to convert the object into an array,

```
        this.values = Object.values(this.searchedInventory);
        console.log(this.values);
      }
```

and the html is,

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of values">
                <td id="values">{{item}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success">Select</button></td>
</tr>
```

now the the array is not printing in row but as a column.
[image: the array is listing items vertically]

Comment: is the data is coming as a array?

Comment: searchedInventory should be an array

Comment: if it's an object, then why are you even using `*ngFor`, just use interpolation `{{searchedInventory.id}}`... If you want to transform object to an array and iterate, see https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: the data is an object

Comment: the searchedInventory will have multiple objects in it. So I have to loop it right?

Comment: then you also need to return an _array of objects_ from the server/service in order to iterate objects with *ngFor

Comment: simplilearn.model.Inventory@af6254c - this is what is returned from the backend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring-boot+return+json+array

Comment: "the searchedInventory has data in it when I console logged it" - that's runtime. A "type X is not assignable to..." error happens at build time. What matters there is not the actual value of `searchedInventory`, but the type declaration of `Inventory`. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

data is coming as an object don't need to iterate it

```
<tr>
        <td>{{searchedInventory.id}}</td>
        <td>{{searchedInventory.foodName}}</td>
        <td>{{searchedInventory.foodDescription}}</td>
        <td>{{searchedInventory.price}}</td>
        <td>{{searchedInventory.date}}</td>
        <td>{{searchedInventory.hotelName}}</td>
        <td>{{searchedInventory.hotelAddress}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-success">Select</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not working, it shows object is possibly undefined. But I can see the result of the object searchedInventory in console.log. Its kind of weird.

Comment: @VishnuGautam, use "safe operator", the `?.`, e.g. `{{searchedInventory?.id}}`

Comment: @Eliseo it is not working. error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Inventory[]'. but in log the property does exist.

Comment: @VishnuGautam, you need know if your "searchedInventory is an array -even if has only one element- or an object (in the question you indicate that it's an Object). Then declare in your component as `searchedInventory:Inventory` or as `searchedInventory:Inventory[]=[]`

Comment: @Eliseo I tried your way again, i get this error : Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Inventory[]'. but when i logged it, it has an object like -  {id: 1, foodName: 'idli', foodDescription: 'made from rice', date: '2023-02-08 15:38:00.86964+05:30', price: 30, …}

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own!!!
Actually the problem was in the backend Springboot,

```
@GetMapping(path="/admin/inventory/search/{food_name}")
        public Inventory getFoodByName(@PathVariable String food_name) {
            Inventory foodname = inventoryService.findByFoodName(food_name);
            if(foodname == null) {
                throw new TodoNotFoundException("foodname - " + food_name);
            }
            return foodname;
        }
```

to,

```
@GetMapping(path="/admin/inventory/search/{food_name}")
        public List<Inventory> getFoodByName(@PathVariable String food_name) {
            Inventory foodname = inventoryService.findByFoodName(food_name);
            if(foodname == null) {
                throw new TodoNotFoundException("foodname - " + food_name);
            }
            List items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(foodname);
            return items;
        }
```

so now my backend return a ArrayList, with which I can iterate using *ngFor and it is executing perfectly!!!

sometimes I need to look a deep into everything to figure out the solution. I was thinking the problem was with the *ngFor!